# How can I prevent labels from overlapping each other in ZedGraph?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I have a ZedGraph stacked bar graph, and I want each bar to show its value on a label.
So far no problem.

But is there any built-in function to prevent labels from overlapping?

Here is a screenshot showing the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just changing the angle property for your labels' `FontSpec`. 
Use i.e. about 30-45 degrees and you have your problem solved.

See:
http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_TextObj.htm

Comment: thanks, but that looks kinda ugly in bars where this is not needed. the labels are centered in the bar. so is there a easy possibility to detect overlapping labels and just rotate them?

Comment: I don't think so. You will probably need to check all labels and validate their rectangle area